# NodeJS, Passport and Mongoose - Sub document issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been developing an application for a few months and it's finally got to the stage where I am ready to deploy it.

Everything is working fine in my development environment and I have no issues.

I'm using Nodejs, Express and MongoDB with Mongoose.

I'm deploying on three servers.
- A reverse proxy Nginx server.
- A server that runs my application.
- A database server.

- The versions of mongoDB and node are the same on the development and live servers.
- All of these servers are running Ubuntu 14.10 and are all up to date fresh installs.
- As suggested in other questions I'm loading mongoose before Express.

The issue is when I go to sign up to the deployed system, my application crashes returning the following error.

```
/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/embedded.js:220
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array.
    at EmbeddedDocument.$isValid (/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/embedded.js:220:11)
    at /Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1022:17
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I've checked the database and it's not adding the sign up data from my online version. So I tried it from my development version. I can add to the database from the development version if I point my data connection string at the online one.

However, when I attempt to log in from there, I submit my log-in form and them am redirected to the home page. I am wondering if that is an issue with data being passed from the mongodb or it is an issue with my nginx setup, as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://IP_ADDRESS:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Any help or points in the right direction would be hugely appreciated. I'm lost and no longer able to google-foo myself out of this one. I'm unsure if it is my web server, a problem with the application or something wrong in the database.

Next step is moving the database on to the application server to see if I can narrow this issue down.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Could you post some relevant code snippets containing the DB interaction logic, too? Another question - how do you deploy? Do you build node modules directly on server or do you just copy them? Could you also try to reinstall all node modules locally to check if this problem occurs too (might be related to a module version or system architecture)?